# how to run minifi as a service in windows 7?

Tags: windows, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I want to run a minifi bat file as a window service.

Is there any way where we can do this in windows 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This addresses your concern!

Let me know if you need more help

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.4.0/minifi-quick-start/content/starting_minifi_on_windows.html